# Java Generics: parse String[] to (T extends Number)[]

Tags: java, generics

I already have this code implemented, and it works just fine:

```
static Integer[] parseInteger(String[] arr){
     return Arrays.stream(arr).map(Integer::parseInt).toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```

But now I look for something like this:

```
public <T extends Number> T[] parseString(String[] arr,T n, Class<T> type){
    return Arrays.stream(arr).map(T::parseNumber).toArray(T[]::new);
}
```

Is there any solution for this problem? Didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

`T::parseNumber` won't work, since there is no `parseNumber` method in `Number`. Furthermore there is no inheritance for `static` methods. Also e.g. `BigInteger` doesn't even offer a `static` method for parsing from `String` and `AtomicInteger` doesn't offer a constructor that takes `String`, so even if you use reflection, you won't get it to work with the implementations of `Number` in the API, let alone all possible implementations...

`T[]::new` doesn't work since you cannot generate a array using a type parameter.

You could change the method to make it work however:

Pass a `Function<String, T>` to parse the `String`s and either pass a `IntFunction<T[]>` to generate the array or use the `Array` class ([see *How to create a generic array in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/530289/2991525)):

```
public <T extends Number> T[] parseString(String[] arr, Function<String, T> parser, Class<T> type){
    return Arrays.stream(arr).map(parser).toArray(size -> (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, size));
}
```

Sample use

```
parseString(new String[]{ "1", "10", "193593118746464111646135179395251592"}, BigInteger::new, BigInteger.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

It cannot work because `Number` is an abstract class that doesn't provide any generic method allowing to parse a `String` into the corresponding `Number` implementation. You will need to provide your own method as next for example:

```
public class NumberParser {
    public static <T extends Number> T parseNumber(String val, Class<T> type) {
        if (type == Double.class) {
            return (T) Double.valueOf(val);
        } else if (type == Float.class) {
            return (T) Float.valueOf(val);
        } else if (type == Integer.class) {
            return (T) Integer.valueOf(val);
        } else if (type == Long.class) {
            return (T) Long.valueOf(val);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown number type");
    }
}
```

**NB:** This generic parser is not meant to be perfect, it just shows the idea.

Then your method will be:

```
public static <T extends Number> T[] parseString(String[] arr, Class<T> type){
    return Arrays.stream(arr).map(s -> NumberParser.parseNumber(s, type))
        .toArray(length ->  (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, length));
}
```

You will then be able to parse your array of `String` generically as next:

```
String[] values = {"1", "2", "3"};
Integer[] result = parseString(values, Integer.class);
for(Integer i : result) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
```